# I clicked clean..and there is no R.java file here

Tags: android, r.java-file

My project now does not contain R.java file
I clicked clean under Project.Now my R.java file contains nothing, so i deleted it and clicked the run button, but still the R.java file is not auto generated, because of the missing file I'm getting errors in my MainActivity.java

Comment: fix errors in resource files

Comment: Clean your project and rebuild it.

Comment: Does theconsole give any hints on errors in your resources?

Comment: first you check that any error in your resources.

Comment: Fix errors in your layout files or resource files if any.

Comment: what is a resource file? MainActivity.java??

Comment: This means that **at least one** of your **xml files** (not necessarily a layout) has at least one (as small as it can be) error.

Comment: any resource under the res folder is a resource file. It could be a misconstructed XML file or an image with an invalid name.

Comment: @FD_ yeas it says- res\drawable-mdpi\Guess.jpg: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]

Comment: Fix the **G** to **g**. It accepts only **lower case** chars!

Comment: @kelmer yes..i do have an error in my console stating res\drawable-mdpi\Guess.jpg: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]

Comment: rename Guess.jpg to guess.jpg in your res folder and also from Source from where you can get that image.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone who tried to clear my error! ITS WORKING!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please go to project and check on build automatically.
eclipse will delete r.java file if any of the xml file contain some error and you go to clean the project.but when u again build your project it regenerate R.java.